# How to add 3 chars into a single char in C?

Tags: c

I have char arrays like this:

```
char a[6] = {49, 50, 54, 49, 49, 54}; // ASCII '1', '2', '6', '1', '1', '6'
char b[2];
```

I want to convert a[0], a[1], a[2] into b[0], and a[3], a[4], a[5] into b[1]. So that I can have like this:

```
b[0] = 126;
b[1] = 116;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: And how would you expect to have those 6 bytes be magically compressed into 2? Also your example of how you would like them to be makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: There never can be a "three byte `char`"! `char` is **always** one byte. And don't use magic numbers. If you mean `'1'`, write it!

Comment: @Olaf: Using `{49, 50, 54, ...` is technically more portable if you absolutely ***need*** for it to be ASCII no matter the system.

Comment: @TimČas: Specifying the output character set is the correct way to do this. Or just use a `u8` prefix for the string literal, UTF-8 is ASCII-compatible. Writing **readable** code is a major target for a programmer.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
b[0] = (a[0] - '0') * 100 + (a[1] - '0') * 10 + (a[2] - '0');
```

and similarly for b[1].

Note that if the characters in `a` are non-numeric, or represent a value outside the range that can be stored in a `char`, then the result will be undefined.

Comment: Well done figuring out the pattern! :-) This felt a bit like a code-breaking exercise...

Comment: Thanks - I've been working on my mind-reading skills! ;-)

Comment: What if the ASCII get bigger than 255 ?

Comment: @rootTraveller: if that happens then the problem statement is incomplete, since the result can not be represented, and no behaviour for such conditions has been specified.

Comment: @PaulR Yes. you should mention it for novice comers.

Comment: @rootTraveller: thanks for the advice - I've added a note re validity of input.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are transforming decimal representations to bytes. `sscanf` can help you deal with this as follows:

```
char a[6] = {49, 50, 54, 49, 49, 54};
signed char b[2];
sscanf(a, "%3hhi%3hhi", &b[0], &b[1]);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ZW5iL0)